# Variable not being formatted with CSS - Magento

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.9

When I echo my own variable to a div container it comes out as plaint text (unformatted). I don't understand why echoing a Magento variable comes out formatted but mine doesn't? Here's my code, in particular the `<?php if(!isset($specialPrice)): { ?>`  section which I created. Here is the code:

```
<div class="product">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"
                                   title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img
                                        src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail') ?>"
                                        alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"/></a>
                                <div class="product-details">
                                    <p class="product-name">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                                    </p>

                                    <?php $specialPrice = $productToCheck->getData('special_price');
                                    $orignalPrice = $productToCheck->getData('price');
                                    ?>
                                    <?php if(!isset($specialPrice)): { ?>
                                        <?php echo $product['price'] ?>
                                    <?php } else: { ?>
                                        <?php echo $specialPrice ?>
                                    <?php } endif ?>

                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Echoing `$product['price']` shows up with its CSS like this:

[image]

but if it enters the ELSE statement to display my variable it shows like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Comment: Well maybe `$product['price']` contains more than you thought it did …? `echo htmlspecialchars($product['price']);` gives what?

Comment: Ah that's true....echoing ```htmlspecialchars``` outputs this:
```<div class="price-box"><span class="regular-price" id="product-price-699"><span class="price">£199.99</span> </span></div>```

Answer (score 0):

$product['price'] returns you a unformatting price value.

Maybe you can call a block function, for example $block->getPrice() and in getPrice() you need to format the price by your custom preferences.

If you want to add styles to your price value then you need to use a magento tag class